# How do you add a window (preferences window) to a SpriteKit game in Mac OS X?

Tags: swift, macos, sprite-kit

I am making a Mac OS X game using SpriteKit. The game involves adding various fields (gravity fields, magnetic fields, pulse fields, etc.) to a screen and throwing balls into the fields and watching them react.

How do I have one of my menu items named "Add Field" open up a new window that has settings on which field to add and other settings?

Comment: A possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068763/create-a-new-window-with-nswindow

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the 'Window' an SKNode (edgeNodeFromRect?), and the settings and buttons etc children of that node?